# How to test React components using React Testing Library and Effector (state manager)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, effector

I'm using [effector](https://effector.dev) and React Testing Library (RTL). In the doc of RTL there is [article](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup) about `customerRender` where we pass `AllTheProviders` as a `wrapper` of the render function.

Question: how to do the same with `effector` (couldn't find Provider there)? And how to mock store(s) since there could be more than one (value for Provider)?

In the end I wanted just to use `render(<Component />)` without passing any extra data, as [doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup) shows.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have to hydrate a scope that should provide your mocked values and pass it into effector provider. It should work well if you'll try something like following:

```
import { Provider } from 'effector-react/ssr';
import { fork, hydrate, root } from 'effector-root';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { $store } from './store' 


const Wrapper = ({ children }: Record<any, any>) => (
  <Provider value={scope}>{children}</Provider>
);

it('Test', async () => {
   const scope = fork(root)

   hydrate(scope, {
      values: [
        [
          $store,
          'value',
        ],
      ],
    });

    const { getByTestId } = render(<TestableComponent />, {
      wrapper: Wrapper,
    });
})
```